# How to attach javascript to dynamic created elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

I've got a javascript rotation function setup. It along with a div element are generated dynamically by a button. I'm having trouble knowing how correctly append this rotation slider for each dynamically created element so it can operate individually for each instead of affecting all of them and only working on the first created element. As seen in the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fqjvd7sa/24/

Rotation Function

```
$(function() {
   $('.s1').slider({
      range: 'min',  
      min: -13,
      max: 13,
      slide: refreshRotate
   });

   function refreshRotate() {
      var rotate = $('.s1').slider('value'),
          x = $('.x');
          x.html(rotate);
      $('.list').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)');
      $('.list').css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)');
      $('.list').css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)');
      $('.list').css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)');
      $('.list').css('transform', 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)');
   }
});
```

Generates Dynamically

```
var dom = {

        // Build the main button
        buildButton: function(){

            // Create new DOM element - div
            var button = document.createElement('div');

            // Set element attribute
            button.setAttribute('id', 'strip');
            button.setAttribute('class', 'newclass');            

            // Style the element
            button.style.width = "500px";
            button.style.height = "400px";
            button.style.margin="0px 10px 0px 30px";
            // Add content - FileAPI
            button.innerHTML = '<div class="s1"></div><div class="list"></div>';

            // Print element
            document.body.appendChild(button);
        }
    };

 document.getElementById("first-div").onclick = dom.buildButton;
```

Comment: You're repeating the `id="panzoom"` every time you add a button. IDs should be unique.

Comment: Yes, I do realize this and have removed the ID, my issue still persists. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you configure the slider only once, for the first image.
To have an independent rotate-slider for each image configure it locally for the single image in the buildButton function. There you can easily create the new elements via jquery and make the necessary one-to-one bindings.

Comment: Heavens "one-to-one bindings",  does this refer to using the jquery .on() event handler to tie the rotate function to the .onclick of the div generator element ? Binding an event to an element is the course i'm taking. http://jsfiddle.net/fqjvd7sa/25/

Answer (score 0):

Using the .each() should have enabled //tilt slider to function for on each .list, instead of only working once. I'm not using #ID's but the slider script does get looped correctly.

```
   var dom = {

        // Build the main button
        buildButton: function(){

            // Create new DOM element - div
            var button = document.createElement('div');

            // Set element attribute
            button.setAttribute('id', 'strip');
            button.setAttribute('class', 'newclass');            

            // Style the element
            button.style.width = "500px";
            button.style.height = "400px";
            button.style.margin="0px 10px 0px 30px";
            // Add content - FileAPI
            button.innerHTML = '<div class="s1"></div><div class="list"></div>';





            // Print element
            document.body.appendChild(button);


            //Tilt Slider

 $('.list').each(function() {   
$(function() {
$('.s1').slider({
range: 'min',  
min: -13,
max: 13,
slide: refreshRotate

});


function refreshRotate() {
var rotate = $('.s1').slider('value'),
x = $('.x');
x.html(rotate);
$('.list').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)');
$('.list').css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)');
$('.list').css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)');
        $('.list').css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)');
        $('.list').css('transform', 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)');
}
});

});




        }
    };





document.getElementById("first-div").onclick = dom.buildButton;
```